# ContextMenu title -> get from clicked listView item

Tags: android

Trying to set ContextMenu title according to the ListView clicked item.
The ListView contains Bookmarks list -> FAVICON + BOOKMARK TITLE

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      menu.add(0, EDIT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_edit);
      menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
      menu.add(0, SHARE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_share);

      AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
      View itemID = (info.targetView);
      menu.setHeaderTitle("bla" + itemID);
    }
```

When I run this code it shows the `android.widget.RelativeLayout@423d2389` or whatever and if I change the `itemID` to `String itemID = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();` I get force close on long click even though no errors are shown in Eclipse or when I run the app.

I also want to get the favicon in the same way...

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

info.targetView is a RelativeLayout, not a TextView. Add android:id attribute to your title TextView (e.g. android:id="@android:id/title") and then get string value by:

```
String title = ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(android.R.id.title)).getText();
```

Comment: WORKED! :)
but it's CharSequence and not String.

Thank you!